# Visual Studio 2005 table rendering order

Tags: visual-studio-2005, reporting, localreport

I'm working in Visual Studio 2005 Reporting and I'm trying to implement a workaround of nesting aggregate functions (I need to perform a Count of Sums).  In the table details row, I have a call to custom code to increment an integer every time the value of one cell is >10, then the footer has a call to a custom code function that just returns that value.

The count was always returned as 0, so I threw in some MsgBox calls and noticed the table footer is being called before the details rows.  I need the table details rows to be called first so that the "get" function in the footer will actually retrieve the value I need.

To be more specific, I'm looking to count the number of times a given table cell, whose value is calculated as `(Sum / (Sum+Sum+Sum)) * 100`, is greater than 10.  Since aggregate functions can't be nested, and the use of aggregates on ReportItems!... can only be done in report headers/footers (in my case not helpful as it will display a different total on each page), I'm left with the option of custom code.

Is there any way to force the details row of a table to be rendered before the table footer?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the table footer, I used a textbox beneath the table, so the table was rendered first, header and details rows, then the report processed the textbox below, leading to the correct value.

Hope that helps anyone that comes across this issue.